# Processing Camel message with Bean component

Tags: java, jboss, apache-camel

I have a Camel route with FTP and Bean component which processes the message. This message is a file on FTP and I would like to get the filename of each file processed. I know how to get files with parameter String, but then I cannot get the filename. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Camel FTP component extends the File component, the File Component adds the following headers when consuming a file:

- `CamelFileName`: Name of the consumed file as a relative file path with offset from the starting directory configured on the endpoint.
- `CamelFileNameOnly`: Only the file name (the name with no leading paths).

You can check out the other available headers in the **"File consumer only"** section of the [File2 documentation page](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html).

In a bean method, you can pass a specific header as a parameter using the `@Simple` annotation giving it the value `"header.<header name>"`. For example:

```
public void processFile(@Body String fileContent, @Simple("header.CamelFileNameOnly") String fileName){
  // your method implementation
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This works perfectly! :)